# Is it feasible to call UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath: from within another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it feasible to call `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method from within another class? I've developing an iPad app which uses `UISplitViewController`, and in one specific detail view's controller (say, settings view controller), I want to set the contents of the master view controller's table view's cell dynamically. So my detail view controller's code is something like the follows:

```
MasterViewController *mvc = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
[mvc setContents];
[mvc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath]; // this is not a valid syntax
```

And I want my users to use one of the detail view controller's some UI components such as a button, and change the cell contents of the master view's table view according to the button action. However, `mvc.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath];` is a invalid syntax and doesn't work, since I don't put in `indexPath` argument. However, I don't know how I can add the argument from within the detail view controller, which doesn't have `indexPath` object.

So is it feasible to alter the cell of the master view controller from within the detail view controller's action? Or is my implementation the correct way to achieve the work here, (which I'm not sure by the way)?

I use Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1.

Comment: is detialviewcontrller loaded on click on table row of master view controller ? if yes you can save that index path on each detailsview controller or you can use selected indexpath in master view controller

Comment: Yes, my detail view controller is loaded by tapping one of the cell in master view controller. I'm not sure what you are saying though... Does it only save the indexPath that is tapped, right? I want to alter the whole cell of the master view controller's table view from within one specific detail view controller, not just the cell that is linked to the detail view controller...

Comment: not cell but whole cell ? what it means ?

Comment: Say, my table view at master view controller has four cells, and one of the cell is linked to the detail view controller that enables users to change the contents of the master table view dynamically. However, does your suggestion only alter the contents of the cell that is linked to the detail view controller, right...?

Comment: Yes but you want to alter all cell. you can refer my answer below to get handle to all cells in master view controller.

Answer (score -1):

you can have all cells in master view controller using method

```
-(UITableViewCell) cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and you can create indexPath depending upon your datasource array which used to populate master view table.

Hope it helps !